# how to refactor array from array to single array using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
const arr = [
  [
    {
      _id: "6136096f4255d84bcb4a7144",
      user_id: "5fbfa729fc46a415ce5503a6",
      picture: [Array],
      timestamp: 1630931311227,
    },
    user: {
      _id: "5fbfa729fc46a415ce5503a6",
      first_name: "ABC",
      last_name: "AAA",
      picture: [Object]
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      _id: "613609414255d84bcb4a7122",
      user_id: "5fbf6f91aff7f3320a906547",
      picture: [Array],
      device_platform: 'ios',
      timestamp: 1630931265409
    },
    user: {
      _id: "5fbf6f91aff7f3320a906547",
      first_name: 'EEE',
      last_name: 'TTT',
      picture: [Object]
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      _id: "613709f49223350dfdaec618",
      user_id: "5fbfa748fc46a415ce5503a8",
      picture: [Array],
      timestamp: 1630996980379
    },
    {
      _id: "613609184255d84bcb4a710a",
      user_id: "5fbfa748fc46a415ce5503a8",
      picture: [Array],
      timestamp: 1630931224383,
    },
    user: {
      _id: "5fbfa748fc46a415ce5503a8",
      first_name: 'GRT',
      last_name: 'GGG',
      picture: [Object]
    }
  ]
]
```

I merged push into the object one were like res = [{_id: ..., user_id: ...},{_id: ..., user_id: ...}] and other one was like user = {_id: 5fbfa748fc46a415ce5503a8, first_name: 'AAA',last_name : 'DD'}

res.user = user;
array.push(res)

I merged two object it bring up this but it does not seems to be correct response.

when I used var merged = [].concat.apply([], arr); it does not work

how to fix with correct format.

Comment: Array is collection of elements not `key-value` like you have in your data set `user: { ...`

Answer (score 0):

Working code! just remove the **user** key from the array, and one note ) use const/let instead of var

```
const arr = [
  [
    {
      _id: "6136096f4255d84bcb4a7144",
      user_id: "5fbfa729fc46a415ce5503a6",
      picture: [Array],
      timestamp: 1630931311227,
    },
   {
      _id: "5fbfa729fc46a415ce5503a6",
      first_name: "ABC",
      last_name: "AAA",
      picture: [Object]
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      _id: "613609414255d84bcb4a7122",
      user_id: "5fbf6f91aff7f3320a906547",
      picture: [Array],
      device_platform: 'ios',
      timestamp: 1630931265409
    },
     {
      _id: "5fbf6f91aff7f3320a906547",
      first_name: 'EEE',
      last_name: 'TTT',
      picture: [Object]
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      _id: "613709f49223350dfdaec618",
      user_id: "5fbfa748fc46a415ce5503a8",
      picture: [Array],
      timestamp: 1630996980379
    },
    {
      _id: "613609184255d84bcb4a710a",
      user_id: "5fbfa748fc46a415ce5503a8",
      picture: [Array],
      timestamp: 1630931224383,
    },
   {
      _id: "5fbfa748fc46a415ce5503a8",
      first_name: 'GRT',
      last_name: 'GGG',
      picture: [Object]
    }
  ]
]

const merged = [].concat.apply([], arr);
console.log(merged);
```